# How to Calculate ScreenToWorld Coefficient | Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I'm in need to convert Screen To World position every frame, but I can only do it on Awake/Start. Im looking for a coefficient, that I can apply every frame. Help wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to / can't use default unity camera's `ScreenToWorldPoint` method every frame/update. You can calculate coefficient on Start by this way:

**Formula:** `MaxRightPointOnWorld / (ScreenWidthInPixels / 2)`

**Easy Implementation:**

```
public Vector2 GetScreenToWorldCoefficient(Camera camera)
{
    Vector2 maxPoint = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(
        new Vector3(Screen.width, 0, -camera.transform.position.z)
    );
    return new Vector2(
        maxPoint.x / (Screen.width / 2)
    );
}
```

Note: this codepiece returns 1 coefficient, for X in my case, but at all times X and Y coefficients are same.

Hope I helped someone. Feedback is welcome.